# Is there any possible way to access this variable from callback?

Tags: javascript, callback, scope

How to access potatos from callback test, potatos anonymous function cannot be modified? Bind and so on doesn't work, anyone have an idea?

```
//This cannot be changed
!function(a){
    //
    let potatos = {
        count: 999
    }
    //
    let garden = {
        /**
         * 
         */
        callbacks: [],
        /**
         * 
         */
        showInfo: function() {
            this.callbacks.forEach((cb) => {
                cb();
            })
        } 
    }
    //
    global.garden = garden;//or window.garden
}();
/**
 * 
 */
function test() {
    console.log(potatos);//Error
}

garden.callbacks.push(test);
garden.showInfo();
```

Comment: Given this code which cannot be changed, no there isn't a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. JavaScript uses [lexical scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scope_vs._dynamic_scope) for variables.

`test` is declared outside of any scope in which `potatoes` exists. It cannot access that variable.